# Quick Question About the creat() System Call mode Argument

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

For a project in my class, I was running into issues reading a file that I created using the creat() system call. To my understanding now, creat() is used to write only. I have since modified my code to create this file using open(), so my question is purely out of curiosity. What is the point of the mode argument then? I originally bitwise ORd read and write permission, and the file descriptor would show that it had those permissions, but when I read the file I got a -1 return value. Just strange to me. I also found this code in the manual, so I'm confused. Why give the file read permission when my program can't read it, but at the same time the descriptor shows that the file has read permission?

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd;
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
char *filename = "/tmp/file";
fd = creat(filename, mode);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat):

> creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equal to O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC.

Because of `O_WRONLY` the file is opened in write only mode.

Use `open`:

```
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
char *filename = "/tmp/file";
fd = open(filename, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, mode);
```

> Why give the file read permission when my program can't read it, but at the same time the descriptor shows that the file has read permission?

File permissions is something different from the mode the file descriptor was opened with. A file is created with read permissions, so you are able to open it for reading, but you open the file in write only mode. Open it for read and writing with `O_RDWR` flag.